# how do we know that integral is non-elementary?

Tags: reference-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

Is there a condition that states that the indefinite integration is [non-elementary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral)?

Comment: You may be interested in this theorem by Liouville: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a decision procedure called the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) that will either tell you that the intergral is non-elementary, or produce an elementary anti-derivative. It is not an easy algorithm to execute, or even implement in a computer algebra system (although the latter has been done), so there is no hope of finding an easy condition for the existence of an anti-derivative.